# How can I make an image fadein and expand with jQuery 1.7

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I've tried a variety of snippets of code, but can't get them to do what I want.

What I want to be able to do is to have an href, which will toggle an image from being hidden/faded out/shrunk, to being expanded/fully visible.

I've looked at the fadein/delay and also animate, but can't fathom out the syntax.

As a separate question, I'm doing this within a tab.  Can I get the tab to then scroll if the image or the text after it, expands beyond the height defined for the tab?

```
#StockTakeSummaryPic {
width:1120px;
height:1px;}

function fncShowImage() {
$('#StockTakeSummaryPic').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    height: 'toggle'
}, 1000, function () {
    // Animation complete.
});
}


<a href="#" onclick="javascript:fncShowImage()">View</a>
```

Code added.

Thanks.

Comment: post some code, animations are not hard, so maybe we could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing thats wrong is that you have the height set to `1px` so when you toggle the height it is toggling between `0` and `1` so its not going to show anyway.

Check out my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NCr4F/1/) I've given three options `toggle`, `fade` and `slide`.  You just have to change the function call to see how they work.

Comment: Thanks.  I used the toggle event.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$('.pic-toggle').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#StockTakeSummaryPic').toggle("slow");
});
</script>


<a class='pic-toggle' href="#">View</a>
```

Try that.

Comment: What does the event.preventDefault() do please?

Comment: Couldn't get the click function to work.  All I did was change the class on the href to being an ID and then changed the selector in the jquery to work on the id.

Comment: Good to hear. The event.preventDefault() function stops the browser from trying to go to the href URL. In your case its only '#' so its no too bad